# ng-show not updating the view

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, angularjs-ng-show

ng-show="my.message" is set to true in http success but it doesn't update the view.

Here is my code:

Controller Js:

```
  lgControllers.controller('FormCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

                $scope.my = {
                    message: false
                };
                $scope.submitForm = function() {                       

                    $http({
                        url: "../saket/ajax.php",
                        data: "email_id=" + $scope.form.emailaddress + "&category_id=" + cat_num + "&action=subscribe",
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                        }
                    }).success(function(data) {

                            $scope.my = {
                                message: true
                            };

                        console.log(data); // http is success
                        console.log($scope.my.message); // gives true

                    }).error(function(err) {
                        "ERR", console.log(err)
                    })
                };

            });
```

Index.html:

```
    <div ng-controller="FormCtrl">
        <div ng-show="my.message">It worked!</div>
    </div>
```

my.message gives true in console but the div remains hidden in the view.

I can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: It should work, can you reproduce in Fiddle? template:http://jsfiddle.net/65yyf23x/

Comment: Try to add a call to $scope.$apply() at the end of your callback

Comment: @K K: It gives this error 
Error: [$rootScope:inprog]

Comment: Try to add logs to your html: `<pre>{{my|json}}</pre>` and check what is going on

Comment: @Maxim It shows false at startup and stays false even after true has been logged in console.

I guess there is some issue in using scope and rootScope. What do you suggest?

Comment: Try to use ` ng-show="$parent.my.message"` instead. Do you use `ng-include` or modals? Seems like your code has parent controller or other stuff

Comment: $parent doesn't help. I know my code should work as also shown in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cfdb6gxq/

But I still can't find where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that you are overwriting the message property, and angularjs is loosing the reference?

```
$scope.my = {
    message: true
;
```

try just :

```
$scope.my.message = true;
```

Comment: @essdil That's not the issue. Tried it with just $scope.message

Comment: yes you are right. It should work with it... I created a fiddle where It is working fine... maybe it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/cfdb6gxq/